# MPlab 8.83 IDE compilation error

Tags: c++, embedded, mplab

I have been working on MPlab 8.83 IDE and when I tried to build a code it kept showing the following message:

> "c:/program files (x86)/microchip/mplab c30/bin/bin/../../lib\libpic30-coff.a(crt0_standard.o)(.init+0x1a):crt0_standard.s: undefined reference to 'main' c:/program files (x86)/microchip/mplab c30/bin/bin/../../lib\libpic30-coff.a(crt0_standard.o)(.init+0x1c):crt0_standard.s: undefined reference to 'main' Link step failed."

Why is that, and how to avoid it?

Comment: Your code is obviously missing a `main` function.

Answer (score 0):

Error - "undefined reference to 'main'"

The error indicates that the 'main' isn't defined in the code.

When creating 'C' code, these elements are required to ensure proper program operation and execution: 
o startup code (crt0_standard.o) to initialize and clear variables, to set up registers and the processor
o a main function 
o Reset conditions that need to be handled

The identifier 'main' is special. It is a must and is first function that executes in a program. 
You must have one and only one 'main' function defined in the code. 
Code associated with 'main', however, is not the first code to execute after Reset. 
Additional code provided by the compiler and known as the runtime startup code is executed first and is responsible for transferring
control to the 'main()' function.
The prototype that should be used for 'main()' is as follows.

```
int main(void);
```

Definition of main in XC16 is as:

```
#include <xc.h>

int main ()
{
    /* Perform Firwware tasks here */ 
    return 0;
}
```